# Proper Set Theory Transformation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if i am using the Inverse Laws Correctly in this transformation: 
1. $\mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap(\mathrm{A}\cup\mathrm{C})\cap(\mathrm{A}\cup\neg\mathrm{C}))$
2. $\mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap\varnothing)$ Inverse Law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you derive the second set? Take a look at the following steps:

$\begin{align}
\mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap(\mathrm{A}\cup\mathrm{C})\cap(\mathrm{A}\cup\mathrm{C}^\complement)) 
& = \mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap(\mathrm{A} \cup ( \mathrm{C} \cap \mathrm{C}^\complement))) ~~ \text{(Distributive law)} \\
& =\mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap(\mathrm{A} \cup \varnothing)) ~~ \text{(Inverse law)} \\
& = \mathrm{A}\cup(\mathrm{B}\cap \mathrm{A}) ~~ \text{(Identity law)} \\ 
& = \mathrm{A} ~~ \text{(Absorption law)}
\end{align}$.

Comment: I see my error now... early morning brain fart! For some reason I thought $(\mathrm{A}\cup\neg\mathrm{C})$ was the inverse of $(\mathrm{A}\cup\mathrm{C})$ LOL! Thanks again Stavros!